# .net / c# test wanted for a non techical MD

Tags: .net

Dear all i am looking for an half finished .net application to test my .net c# applicants.

As I come from a differnt coding background, it is difficult for me to assess people skills hence a great test would do a good job!

Regarding checking candidates' test performance, I can ask a friend, no problem !

Does a practical test exist out there? Would I need to pay for it?

Answer (score 1):

To create a suitable C# program for this purpose, it would help to know exactly you're trying to measure:

- Knowledge or skills (or both)?
- Desktop, web, or server?
- Basic, intermediate, or advanced?
- Development or maintenance?
- With or without database knowledge?
- Error-handling and reliability?
- Performance?
- Security?
- UI?
- Algorithms?
- Testing?
- Base class library knowledge?
- .......

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend giving the applicant a small problem to solve during the interview. Have them write out a solution to the problem on the white board in pseudo code and have them explain their thought process.

Once they've done that, then give them access to a computer with the necessary tools installed and watch them code up the solution.

My favorite interview problem is converting to roman numerals.

Comment: I agree with most of this but the "watch them code up the solution" would be rather time-consuming for an interview no?

Comment: I don't think so. If they spend more than thirty minutes coding up a solution, then either the question is too big, or you don't want to hire them. The idea is too find out how they work.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds a nice idea but I am still keen on getting a proper c# test done infront of a PC within a controlled environment where the developer would need to read the code, understand what it does and add his necessary amends.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Road Warrior thanks !

here my answer:

I need to test:

Knowledge and skills web and sql
   intermediate skills maintenace 60%
   developemnt 40% with DB knowledge
   Error-handling and reliability
   Performance as the is has high
   traffic Hybernate

Nothing else

Comment: fwiw, it would be better if you posted this as a comment, and if you had just the one user account

Answer (score 0):

This site may be of interest to you. He talks about hiring programmers and has a decent example of the "fix this smelly code" test.

[http://codebetter.com/blogs/karlseguin/archive/2006/12/01/How-to-hire-a-programmer-*2D00*-Part-2-*2D00*-Improve-this-code.aspx](http://codebetter.com/blogs/karlseguin/archive/2006/12/01/How-to-hire-a-programmer-_2D00_-Part-2-_2D00_-Improve-this-code.aspx)